# How can I pass a Context object to a thread on call

Tags: java, android

I have this code fragment:

```
public static class ExportDatabaseFileTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> 
{
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);

    protected void onPreExecute();
    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args);
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success);
}
```

I execute this thread as

```
new ExportDatabaseFileTask().execute();
```

As you see I use a ctx as Context variable in the new ProgressDialog call, how do I pass a context to the call method?

to this one:

```
new ExportDatabaseFileTask().execute();*
```

Comment: Why would you have the ProgressDialog inside an AsyncTask?
I always place it in my activity and update it using publishProgress

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the way, I had to create my own constructor, and lose the static stuff

```
        public ExportDatabaseFileTask(Context ctx) {
            super();
            this.ctx=ctx;
            dialog= new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        }
```

Comment: yes  ok that also works.... i thought the static keyword is necessary and in static classes you can't define constructors.

Comment: actually I need the static keyword in front of the class name, otherwise can't recognize it, but I make a new instance of it.

Comment: ty this has been annoying me for hours.

Answer (score 1):

Just define a static setter method where you can pass the Context object

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this in the Dev Guide and I believe that is exactly its purpose. `android.content.ContextWrapper`